# SSIS variable from excel file

Tags: sql-server, excel, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have a stored procedure on a server which generates a table in my database. Then in ssis I'm querying some columns from that table and then I'm appending some dummy columns filled with static values. When I query the database I'm doing it so by holding the query into a variable (sql command from variable), in that query I am using a select a, b, c from X where @[User::variable1] = '' and @[User::variable2]='' for all 4.
My question is: I need to be able to change the value of those variables (variable1 to 4) for 48 different scenarios (or might be more than that), so manually replacing them would be a pain since it will lead to over 130 combos. If there a way in which I could pass the values from an excel file at runtime to the package?
ex:

```
column1        column2  column3 column4
12.03.2015       def     ghi     jkl
12.04.2015       456     789     012

..

..
```

And I need to loop through all columns in the excel file and the results should be exported to files. 
What I described above I already made except for the part in which I can get the values for those 4 variables from the excel file. I need help only with this part.

Any help would be great.
Thank you,
Cristian

Comment: Your overall issue isn't very clear, but to answer your question, you could pre-load the excel file into a table and then query the table at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

1. Create a Connection to Excel
2. Create a Transit table to store the excel content (obviously the column names)
3. Create a "Data Flow" Task to transfer the content from Excel into the Transit Table
4. Create an "Execute SQL Task"
5. Get one by one row from Transit table in a loop or Cursor
6. Dynamically create a SQL string with the value read from the Transit Table
7. Execute it by using sp_executesql.
8. Use "Result set" if you want to output any recordset

Comment: created the connection to excel, using the excel file as a source and as a destination a recordset (on the input columns i select all 4), and n component properties/variable name i have a variable which of type object. Then i created a forloop in which i am using as an enumerator a Foreach ADO enumerator and i'm setting the ADO object source variable as the object variable mentioned above. The enumeration mode is :rows in the first table.  /part 1

Comment: I am mapping my 4 variables which are the column names from the excel file (which are also being used in a task later on in the query i'm doing over the table generated by the procedure) with indexes from 0 to 3. How to pass the values from here to my query? so it will use those 4 variables everytime in a loop. What am i missing?